Regarding silicon-based life, how would using silane instead of silicone in chemical compounds change how the lifeform works?
All I currently know is that they require cryogenic solvents, cold temperatures, hydrogen to breathe, and only inhale. What else should I know for using silane in silicon lifeforms?

Edit the previous question. Do not delete and repost. Btw, this edit makes the question sensibly worse.

How does this site work ;-;
I tried reading the how to make a good question thing, how is this worse?
